# Objective C assigning a dictionary to a variable and accessing it

Tags: objective-c, variables, nsdictionary

I'm sorry to ask this question again, but I'm still stuck.

I have a city object trying to fetch weather from a weather fetcher object

```
@interface WeatherFetcher : NSObject {

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *weatherData;

- (void)fetchWeather:(NSString *)cityName;
- (void)handleNetworkErorr:(NSError *)error;
- (void)handleNetworkResponse:(NSData *)myData;

@end
```

This is were I assign the value to weatherData

```
#import "WeatherFetcher.h"

@implementation WeatherFetcher

- (void)fetchWeather:(NSString *)cityName
{
    NSString *urlString = @"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:cityName];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@",Aus"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                               if (connectionError)
                               {
                                   [self handleNetworkErorr:connectionError];
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   [self handleNetworkResponse:data];
                               }
                           }];
}

#pragma mark - Private Failure Methods

- (void)handleNetworkErorr:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Please try again later" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    [alert show];
}

#pragma mark - Private Success Methods

- (void)handleNetworkResponse:(NSData *)myData
{
    //NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // now we'll parse our data using NSJSONSerialization
    id myJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    // typecast an array and list its contents
    NSDictionary *jsonArray = (NSDictionary *)myJSON;

    //NSLog([jsonArray description]);

    // take a look at all elements in the array
    for (id element in jsonArray) {

        id key = [element description];

        id innerArr = [jsonArray objectForKey:key];

        NSDictionary *inner = (NSDictionary *)innerArr;

        if ([inner conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSFastEnumeration)]) {

            for(id ele in inner) {

                if ([ele conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSFastEnumeration)]) {

                    NSDictionary *innerInner = (NSDictionary *)ele;

                    for(id eleEle in innerInner) {

                        id innerInnerKey = [eleEle description];
                        [data setObject:[[inner valueForKey:innerInnerKey] description] forKey:[eleEle description]];
                    }
                }
                else {

                    id innerKey = [ele description];
                    [data setObject:[[inner valueForKey:innerKey] description] forKey:[ele description]];
                }
            }
        }
        else {

            [data setObject:[inner description] forKey:[element description]];
        }
    }

    self.weatherData = data;
    NSLog([self.weatherData description]) **//there is data**
}

@end
```

However every time I call this from by city object I get nothing back at all.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "WeatherFetcher.h"

@interface City : NSObject {

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cityName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stateName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *cityPicture;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *weather;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *weatherData;

-(NSString *)getWeather;

@end
```

UI calls getWeather by a button press to get the string value to be displayed on screen

```
@implementation City {


}

-(NSString *)getWeather {

    //return self.weather;

    NSString *info = @"";
    WeatherFetcher *weatherFetcher = [[WeatherFetcher alloc] init];
    [weatherFetcher fetchWeather:self.cityName];
    self.weatherData = [weatherFetcher weatherData];

    for (id element in self.weatherData) {

        info = [info stringByAppendingString:[element description]];
        info = [info stringByAppendingString:@"-->"];
        info = [info stringByAppendingString:[self.weatherData valueForKey:[element description]]];
        info = [info stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
    }

    return info;
}

@end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

getWeather method in the city class gets called when a button is pressed and I'm trying to display this string in a text area. I don't have much experience with Objective C and this is my first app other than Hello World app.

Thank you!

Comment: This time, when someone leaves you a comment, add another comment to answer their question. Otherwise it just looks like you went to sleep, people get pissed off and don't want to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to format the text in the comments section and I can't seems to get the code to display properly, that's why I opened a new question, and thought it might help to show the whole code

Comment: You do asynchronous processing in the `fetchWeather:` method. You attempt to process the results long before they are obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WeatherFetcher` is *asynchronous*  (`sendAsynchronousRequest:`) - it sets a task to obtain the data and then returns (usually) *before* that data has been obtained. So when you try to access the `weatherData` immediately after the call to `fetchWeather:` it is not there yet.

You need to redesign your model to handle asynchronicity - `getWeather` cannot be synchronous. For example you could make `fetchWeather:` take a completion block to invoke when the data is available and have `getWeather` pass in a suitable block.

Comment: I'm a complete beginner, could you please give me an example?
many thanks

Comment: @Archie - the example is your `weatherFetcher`, in that you call `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` and pass a block to be called when the request is done. You need to repeat that pattern to suit your application. So you could change `fetchWeather:` to `fetchWeather:completionHandler:` and have your current `handleNetworkResponse:` finish by calling the block passed to `fetchWeather`, etc. Change your model from synchronous method call/return to an asynchronous one where method calls don't return values but pass them to completion blocks - read up on asynchronous design.